# While left shift operator (<<) using before std::cout , what does it work for?

Tags: c++, c++11, error-handling, compiler-errors, bitwise-operators

Those code lines:

```
std::cout << "observerIndex : " <<
std::cout << pobserverIndex -> observerInt() ;
```

Generate the compiler error below:

```
file.C:2917:37: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>' and 'std::basic_ostream<char>')
     std::cout << "observerIndex : " <<
                                     ^
```

Could anyone please tell me what left shift operator(`<<`) is doing on there (before `std::cout << pobserverIndex -> observerInt()`)?

Comment: It uses a technique called *operator overloading*. Essentially `<<` is syntactic sugar for a function name, that's all. Do google the term. Your compile error is probably due to a missing semicolon on the first line.

Comment: It does nothing, it's broken code, as your compiler is telling you.

Comment: The author of the code most likely made a typo. It should probably be a semicolon `;` instead of `<<`.

Comment: Your code should be `std::cout << "observerIndex: " << pobserverIndex -> observerInt() ;`

Comment: std::cout<<"hiiiii" <<
 std::cout<<"senturkkkkkk"; // when i compiled this lines it gives this hiiiiii0x486a08senturkkkkk . Why ?

Comment: i think it has different mean, using this operator (<<) alone doing something

Comment: Streams are [implicitly convertible to pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) so they can be used in boolean expressions to check the status of the stream.

Comment: `std::cout<<"abc"` means `std::cout.operator<<("abc")`

Comment: @Yves yes i know but it is different  std::cout<<"abc"**<<**std::cout<<"abc"

Comment: @Yves No, for strings the [`operator<<` function is a non-member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude . Thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing a semicolon at the end of your first statement, plus you are repeating `std::cout`.

You need to use

```
std::cout << "observerIndex: " << pobserverIndex -> observerInt();
```

A variant like

```
std::cout << "a" << std::cout<< "b";
```

is outputting the *address* of the object `cout` in the `std` namespace, formatted as hexadecimal, between the strings "a" and "b".